# Is it necessary to wrap the continuation that will be in non-GUI thread with Task.Run?

Tags: c#, async-await

This question is for learning purposes. I am not in developing anything for sure.

I have two long running CPU-bound operations (`JobA` and `JobB`). Both do not interact with the GUI. Unlike `Task.FromResult` that completes immediately at the await expression, my `Task.Run(()=>JobA()).ConfigureAwait(false)` will return control to the caller and causes the continuation to be executed in non-GUI thread (because of `ConfigureAwait(false)`).

```
static void  JobA()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) ;
}

static void JobB()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) ;
}


private static async Task Async()
{            
    await Task.Run(()=>JobA()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    JobB();
    //await Task.Run(() => JobB());
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    await Async();
}
```

## Question

In my understanding, wrapping `JobB` with `Task.Run` as in the second case below is unnecessary because the continuation is already guaranteed to run in non-GUI thread.

```
private static async Task Async()
{            
    await Task.Run(()=>JobA()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    JobB();
}

private static async Task Async()
{            
    await Task.Run(()=>JobA()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Task.Run(() => JobB());
}
```

`Exception` behavior in asynchronous is a bit tricky so I am asking this question because I want to know whether eliding is risky when exception occurs. If there is no such risk, I will delete this question.

Comment: You ask if it is necessary without saying what condition you wish to achieve. If I asked you "is it necessary to heat the pot to boiling temperature?" but did not say what I was cooking, I assume you would have difficulty answering. Can you clarify what condition you are attempting to achieve? For instance, is there a requirement that `JobB` run on the UI thread?

Comment: If you changed the return type of JobA and JobB to Task then you could async await  the function and get rid of Task.Run within your Async() call.

Comment: You're making the question more confusing, not less confusing, with your edits. Suppose I said "here are two workflows, workflow one: count to ten. Workflow two: ask a friend to count to ten; while they are counting, go do other work. They'll let you know when they're finished".  My question for you is **what is the difference between those workflows?** How would one even begin to answer that question?

Comment: Technically the second method will spend bit more time on reclaiming thread occupied by continuation when it completes and then immediately will request another thread from the pool. If that is what you're asking in the question.

Comment: But from other hand the second is more readable - it better conveys the intentions.

Comment: However if you deal with I/O-bound operations it would make more difference. As in the first case the `JobB()` has high chances to be executed in a thread which belongs to I/O thread pool. The general requirement to any workload executed in such threads is to complete execution as quick as possible to make the thread available for other I/O completion operations. In that case executing a long-running operation in continuation isn't the best choice.

Comment: Technically it will continue on the Thread Pool thread but tell it to the developer that will be refactoring this. I would stick with 2 awaits. It's too much voodoo otherwise.

Comment: @ZakkDiaz converting `JobA` and `JobB` to Task-returning async methods will not make these tasks to run on a thread-pool thread. They will run synchronously. You could trick them to run asynchronously by adding something like `await Task.Yield();` or `await Task.Delay(1);` inside the methods, but this is dirty and probably unreliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my Task.Run(()=>JobA()).ConfigureAwait(false) will return control to the caller and causes the continuation to be executed in non-GUI thread (because of ConfigureAwait(false))

Really? Are you *sure?*

One interesting aspect of `await` is that it behaves synchronously if possible. So if the task has already completed by the time `await` checks it, then `await` will continue running synchronously. In this scenario, `ConfigureAwait` has no effect.

Notably, this can happen when you have different computers with different CPU speeds, or memory available, or cache behavior. With a dose of Murphy's Law, you end up with a production issue that you can't reproduce, which is always fun.

So, I *never* rely on `ConfigureAwait(false)` to guarantee that any code is running on a thread pool thread. That's what `Task.Run` is for. For the simple case you posted, you can do one job after another within the `Task.Run`: `await Task.Run(() => { JobA(); JobB(); });`

Comment: As I said in the question, the long running operations will not complete by the time await checks it so I am very sure it will be asynchronously executed. Therefore, the remaining will be in non-GUI thread. :-)